# Modificar posicionamento de elementos utilizando HTML e CSS

Tags: html, css

Estou com problemas pra fazer um ícone ficar na lateral de um elemento sem que ele se sobreponha ao elemento.

Meu código:

```css
body{
    font-family: Times, serif;
    text-align: justify;
    background-color: #EBE9E9;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

p{
    text-align: justify;
    text-indent: 1pt;
}

.icone{
    display: block;
    font-size: 3.4em;
    margin: 4.5%;
}

.lateraldireita{
    position: relative;
    float:left
}

.grupo{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 50%
    top: 2em;
    left: 2em;
    padding: 1em;
    margin-left: 10em;
    margin-top: 2em;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid rgba(193, 193, 193, 0.3);
    border-radius: 1px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(193,193,193,0.5);
    transition: 3s;
}

hr{
    display: block;
    background-color: #444;
    color: #555;
    height:0.01px;
}

.blocointerno{
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 20em;
    left: 25em;
    margin-left: -15;
}
```

```html
<aside class="lateraldireita">
    <article class="grupo experiencia">
                <i class="fas fa-check-double icone"></i>
                <div class="blocointerno">
                    <h3>Experiências Profissionais</h3>
                    <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h4>
                    <p>JAN 2013 - SET 2014</p>
                    <p>Ut faucibus lacinia orci, quis consectetur purus facilisis vitae. Vestibulum blandit fringilla pharetra. Donec odio odio, ultricies sed venenatis vitae, dapibus in felis. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aenean ornare egestas leo, viverra finibus justo ornare in. Etiam aliquet libero sed ante scelerisque commodo. Vestibulum ut feugiat ante. Maecenas nec fringilla ante, eu hendrerit magna. Nullam consectetur cursus est at vestibulum. Sed consequat, mauris quis hendrerit facilisis, orci velit hendrerit tortor, ac consectetur nibh dolor non arcu.</p>
                </div>
            </article>
</aside>
```

Como eu quero que o ícone se comporte:

[image: detalhe do elemento de referência]

Tentei:

- Criar um bloco interno, o que ajudou um pouco;
- usar um `position: absolute`, o que não ajudou muita coisa;
- e até mudar o `left` do bloco interno, mas ele não obedece.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilize *flexbox* na classe `.grupo` ou `.experiencia`. No exemplo abaixo, como já existe um bloco de propriedades para a classe `.grupo`, basta trocar o `display: block` por `display: flex`:

```css
body{
        font-family: Times, serif;
        text-align: justify;
        background-color: #EBE9E9;
        color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
        word-wrap: break-word;
    }

    p{
        text-align: justify;
        text-indent: 1pt;
    }

.icone{
    display: block;
    font-size: 3.4em;
    margin: 4.5%;
}

    .lateraldireita{
        position: relative;
        float:left
    }

    .grupo{
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        /* width: 50%; */
        top: 2em;
        left: 2em;
        padding: 1em;
        margin-left: 10em;
        margin-top: 2em;
        background-color: white;
        border: 1px solid rgba(193, 193, 193, 0.3);
        border-radius: 1px;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(193,193,193,0.5);
        transition: 3s;
    }

    hr{
        display: block;
        background-color: #444;
        color: #555;
        height:0.01px;
    }

    .blocointerno{
        display: block;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        width: 20em;
        left: 25em;
        margin-left: -15;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
<aside class="lateraldireita">
    <article class="grupo experiencia">
       <i class="fas fa-check-double icone"></i>
       <div class="blocointerno">
           <h3>Experiências Profissionais</h3>
           <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h4>
           <p>JAN 2013 - SET 2014</p>
           <p>Ut faucibus lacinia orci, quis consectetur purus facilisis vitae. Vestibulum blandit fringilla pharetra. Donec odio odio, ultricies sed venenatis vitae, dapibus in felis. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aenean ornare egestas leo, viverra finibus justo ornare in. Etiam aliquet libero sed ante scelerisque commodo. Vestibulum ut feugiat ante. Maecenas nec fringilla ante, eu hendrerit magna. Nullam consectetur cursus est at vestibulum. Sed consequat, mauris quis hendrerit facilisis, orci velit hendrerit tortor, ac consectetur nibh dolor non arcu.</p>
       </div>
   </article>
</aside>
```

Answer (score 0):

Considerando que a sua classe `.grupo` estava com `position: relative;` (não entendi o porque), bastou:

- alterar o posicionamento do ícone, através da classe `.icone`:

  ```
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 15px;
  ```
- adicionar uma margem à esquerda da classe `.blocointerno`:

  ```
  margin-left: 60px;
  ```

---

No final das contas, encontrei vários problemas no seu CSS. Não "reformulei" seu código por completo, mas melhorei alguma coisa superficial:

```css
body{
    font-family: Times, serif;
    text-align: justify;
    background-color: #EBE9E9;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

.lateraldireita{
    /* position: relative; */
    float:left;
}

.grupo{
    position: relative;
    /* display: block; */
    /* width: 50%; */
    top: 2em;
    left: 2em;
    padding: 1em;
    margin-left: 10em;
    margin-top: 2em;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid rgba(193, 193, 193, 0.3);
    border-radius: 1px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(193,193,193,0.5);
    transition: 3s;
}

.icone{
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: 15px;
    font-size: 3.4em;
}

.blocointerno{
    /* display: block; */
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 20em;
    left: 25em;
    margin-left: 60px;
    /* margin-left: -15; */
}

p{
    text-align: justify;
    text-indent: 1pt;
}

hr{
    display: block;
    background-color: #444;
    color: #555;
    height:0.01px;
}
```

```html
<link
    rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css"
    integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
<aside class="lateraldireita">
    <article class="grupo experiencia">
       <i class="fas fa-check-double icone"></i>
       <div class="blocointerno">
           <h3>Experiências Profissionais</h3>
           <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h4>
           <p>JAN 2013 - SET 2014</p>
           <p>Ut faucibus lacinia orci, quis consectetur purus facilisis vitae. Vestibulum blandit fringilla pharetra. Donec odio odio, ultricies sed venenatis vitae, dapibus in felis. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aenean ornare egestas leo, viverra finibus justo ornare in. Etiam aliquet libero sed ante scelerisque commodo. Vestibulum ut feugiat ante. Maecenas nec fringilla ante, eu hendrerit magna. Nullam consectetur cursus est at vestibulum. Sed consequat, mauris quis hendrerit facilisis, orci velit hendrerit tortor, ac consectetur nibh dolor non arcu.</p>
       </div>
   </article>
</aside>
```